# Permanently dot Source a File?

Tags: powershell, dot-source

I am using a Custom-Powershell-Script all the time. I simply can Dot-Source the File, but I have to do this in every session.

```
. .\Hello-World.ps1
```

Is there a way to dot-source a file permanently? I don't want to do this over and over again.

Comment: Just put it in your profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check first your profiler is present or not.

```
Test-Path $profile
```

If it is returning *False*, we have to create them. Run PS in elevated mode.

```
New-Item -path $profile -type file –force
```

So it will ask the confirmation.

Open the file named *Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1* from the path and add the entry there directly like:

```
. .\Hello-World.ps1
```

Once done,Save and restart it. If you open it again, you should be able to see the Dot Source Functions present in the Hello-World.ps1

By default **$profile** path should be:

`C:\Users\Username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`

Hope it helps.

Comment: You should take care where you put the sourced file, probably at the end so it will not be overwritten.

Comment: @Timo: True.. But if your source file is having functions then you need to put it somewhere before calling the function.